# how to import a lambda function code into eclipse

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, eclipse, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

we have a lambda function written in java already deployed. I am trying to make a minor change to it. we dont have the source code for it.

I tried to export the function as a zip file. The export worked, but it has .class files in it.

I tried to import the zip file into eclipse, but eclipse would not recognize it as a java project.

what are my options here. How can i get the .java files code from this exported lambda.

Comment: Classs files don't contain the Java source code, just the compiled byte code. If that is all you have you can try a Java decompiler but the result won't be as good as the original source.

Comment: There's no git or other repo somewhere with this code? What about the previous developer who may have a local copy of the source code?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a really good way to do this  - certainly no out of the box way to import the ZIP file into Eclipse. What you can try is to unzip the ZIP file to a local folder. that will give you CLASS files.

[image]

FRom there- try using a [Java Decompiler](http://java-decompiler.github.io/) to decompile the Java class files to get the source code (it will not be as good as the source code however). Then import the Java source files back into a Java IDE.